# How can I add 2 binary int arrays in C#

Tags: c#, binary

I'm a programming student and I need a function that would add 2 binary int arrays in C#. I need to use the %. I spent the day looking for a way to do it but I don't find anything. How would you guys make it? The 2 numbers to add will always have the same amount of bits

I tried this

```
for(int i = nb1.Length; i>= 0; i--) {
   reponse[i] = (nb1[i] + nb2[i]) % 2;
 }
```

But it's not working because I need to count the number of cycle that I skipped

I want something like this

```
int[] nb1 = [0, 0, 1, 1]
int[] nb2 = [0, 1, 0, 1]

expected output = [1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Thanks!

Comment: *it's not working* is a very poor problem description.  Please visit the [help] and study some of the topics there such as [ask] to learn how to effectively use the site.

Comment: Can you add an example which shows the values in the two input arrays and the expected output values. It's not immediately clear from the description what you're trying to do and why you are trying to use the mod (%) operator

Comment: Where higher bits are located: at the begining or at the end of the array? Now your algorithm do not take into account that if the sum of the two lower bits (say at position *n*) is larger than 1 then you need to use this fact when calculating sum of the bits at the position *n+1*. Do you want us to write a working algorithm or just describe it so then you will be able to implement it by yourself?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "binary int array" so you'll have to describe what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to sum it up as ordinary numbers, but with base of 2

```
int mem = 0;
for(int i = nb1.Length; i>= 0; i--) {
   reponse[i] = (mem + nb1[i] + nb2[i]) % 2;
   mem = mem + nb1[i] + nb2[i] >= 2 ? 1 : 0;
}
if (mem != 0) {
   response.Add(1);
}
```